# How to remotly validate an installation for a basic user?

Tags: windows, permissions, configuration, user-permissions, administrative-privileges

We have 10 PC on the network and we don't have ActiveDirectory.
Actually, every time than a user (they aren't admin on their computer) want to install a software, I use TeamViewer to access the computer and install the application manually with the admin password.

It's not easy... Do you have better solution for enable admin privilege remotly for an installation ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: AD would be that solution. Or [App Deployment in Microsoft Intune](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/library/dn646955.aspx).

Comment: Who would be performing the installation - you or the users?

Comment: In the ideal case, it's the user but the admin made the validation remotly (without the combo TeamViewer&password manually)